Need Help Understanding Google Error Prone in Maven for Tracking Errors and Warnings
I’m a new developer, and I’m currently working on a project where Google Error Prone is being used in our Maven build process. However, I’m quite confused about how it works and how I should be using it to find errors, count warnings, and possibly suppress certain warnings.
Here’s what I’m dealing with:

In our pom.xml, we have the following configuration related to Google Error Prone:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${org.apache.maven.plugins.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>17</source>
        <target>17</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-XDcompilePolicy=simple</arg>
            <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
            <!-- Uncomment the line below for enabling "error-prone". -->
            <arg>-Xplugin:ErrorProne</arg>
            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            <arg>-Xmaxwarns</arg>
            <arg>1000</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
                <artifactId>error_prone_core</artifactId>
                <version>${com.google.errorprone.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>


I need to achieve the following:

Find and count the errors and warnings in the project.
Suppress certain warnings if possible.
Track the count of warnings and possibly errors.


I’m not sure where to start:

What does Google Error Prone do in this configuration? Is it just finding errors, or is it also counting and displaying warnings?
How do I see the errors and warnings detected by Error Prone? Will they show up in the Maven console output, or do I need to check somewhere else?
Is <showWarnings>true</showWarnings> necessary for my use case? What does it actually do?
How can I track the number of warnings or errors generated by Error Prone? Is there a specific way to get these counts?


As someone who’s new to this, I’d really appreciate it if someone could explain how to configure this plugin and use it effectively based on my level of understanding. I’m eager to learn and improve!


Thank you in advance for your help!
